# Java Utility to convert content of any file to text file.

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am looking for a java utility through which a user can convert any type of file (pdf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, csv, rtf, txt). We have a requirement in which user can upload any type of file and we need to read the content of the file(only text), convert it and store it in an object. That can be done using Apachi poi but I am wondering if any java utility exists?

Comment: What is your programming question? Such an utility would either be very error prone (not specific enough) or very hard to develop (taking into account many specific cases) and therefore proprietary (e.g. used for search engines).

Comment: For parsing PDF you can use PDFBox: http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: Christophe, As javier has given the link for apache tikka and its using internally PDFBox. Its not only about pdf, i need to parse other formats also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), which includes the functionality of Apache POI and PDFBox. From the project description, the toolkit: "*detects and extracts metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries.*"

Comment: Thanks Javier, Apache Tika looks good and fulfilling my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can't have some sort of universal function for every type of file. You will need to implement conversion methods for each file type. [This link](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/itext/convertpdfToTextFile.html) helps with PDF files, and will also give you a template to work with your other file types.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the comment, however I would personally never recommend anyone to use roseindia.net. Trust me this is the worst site to learn something.